# Can't access all Naoqi methods

Tags: nao-robot, pepper, choregraphe

I try to use some methods of http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/audio/alaudioplayer-api.html

But the terminal tells me that most of them don't work.

```
# -*- encoding: UTF-8 -*-

import sys
import time
from naoqi import *

IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 9559

try:
    aup = ALProxy("ALAudioPlayer", IP, PORT)
except Exception,e:
    print "Could not create proxy to ALAudioPlayer"
    print "Error was: ",e
    sys.exit(1)

#this line works. I can hear the music
fileId = aup.post.playFile("C:\VALIDPATH.wav")

#does not show most of the methods
print(aup.getMethodList())

time.sleep(1)

#this line does not work
currentPos = aup.getCurrentPosition(fileId)
```

The output :

> ['isStatsEnabled', 'enableStats', 'stats', 'clearStats',
>   'isTraceEnabled', 'enableTrace', 'exit', '__pCall', 'pCall',
>   'version', 'ping', getMethodList', 'getMethodHelp', 'getModuleHelp',
>   'wait', 'isRunning', 'stop', 'getBrokerName', 'getUsage', 'playFile',
>   'playFileInLoop', 'playFileFromPosition', 'pause']
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "fggfgf.py", line 27, in
>   
>       currentPos = aup.getCurrentPosition(fileId)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\naoqi.py", line 301, in **call**
>       return self.**wrapped**.method_missing(self.**method**, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\naoqi.py", line 371, in method_missing
>       raise e RuntimeError:   ALAudioPlayer::getCurrentPosition
>           Can't find method: getCurrentPosition (resolved to '(i)')

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you linked is a documentation for Naoqi 2.5, are you using a Naoqi 2.5 ?

If so I will say that ALProxy is deprecated and your code should more looks like this:

```
import qi

session = qi.Session()
try:
  session.connect(IP, PORT)
expect Exception e:
  print "Could not connect: %s" % e

try:
  audioplayer = session.service("ALAudioPlayer")
expect Exception e:
  print "Could not get service: %s" % e
  return

audioplayer.playFile(PATH) // synchrone
audioplayer.playFile(PATH, _async=True) // asynchrone

dir(audioplayer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a file path that is on the robot. E.g. 
/data/home/nao/.local/share/PackageManager/apps/soundsetaldebaran/sfx_scanner.ogg"

Comment: I was testing on my computer and the file can be played when I use playFile() method.